# WP7 - Text to speech API

Tags: windows-phone-7, text-to-speech

I'm finding it impossible to create any form of text to speech program. I've scoured the internet and can only find two examples, neither of which work. I've already got and used my Bing app ID so it's not a missing ID causing the problem.

Does anybody know where there is a working example or could provide some sample (functioning!) code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows Phone Platform if you want get be work with Text To Speech. There are be have two you can be choose：

【1】Bing Search Text To Speech Service ：http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/259727/Text-to-speech-in-windows-phone7

【2】About TTX Nuance Dragon SDK have Been Support Windows Phone Platform :  http://www.nuance.com/for-developers/dragon/index.htm